# Square-integrability of derivative of square-integrable function

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to show (or disprove, I'm not entirely certain) that given any solution $y(x) \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ of the following ODE
$$
y''(x)=f(x)y(x)
$$
where $f(x)$ is a bounded and continuos function, then $y'(x) \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$. That is, my guess is that if $y(x) \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ is a solution from the (ODE), then, $y'(x) \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ too. Also, we are dealing with complex functions.

This is my attempt so far.

It can be easily checked that $y''(x) \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ since $f(x) \in L_{\infty}$, $y(x) \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ $\implies$ $f(x)y(x)=y''(x) \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$.

Now, by  noticing that $\frac{d}{dx}(y(x)y^{*}{'}(x)) = y(x)y^{*}{''}(x)+y'(x)y^{*}{'}(x)$, we can write (yes, it merely is integration by parts... I just like to phrase it that way)
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}y'(x)y^{*}{'}(x)dx = \left[y(x)y^{*}{'}(x)\right]_{\mathbb{R}}  - \int_{\mathbb{R}}y(x)y^{*}{''}(x)dx
$$

Then, since the term $\int_{\mathbb{R}}y(x)y^{*}{''}(x)dx$ is finite (inner product of $y(x)$ and $y''(x)$ in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$), we only need to check
$$
\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} y(x)y^{*}{'}(x) < \infty
$$

I have the "intuition" that $y^{*}{'}(x)$ needs to be at least bounded so that $y^{*}{''}(x)$ can be square-integrable but I am not pretty certain of how to prove this or if this or any of the claims above are actually true.

Also, I am unable to find any counterexamples but if you know of one, please let me know.

Comment: $y''=-y$ has solutions $\sin(x),\cos(x)$, and neither of these solutions has its first derivative in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: That is true but doesn't answer my question. I am also assuming $y(x) \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ and neither $\sin(x)$, $\cos(x)$ satisfy that condition.

Comment: I gave you an example--namedly $y''=(-1)y$ (your $f$ is $-1$, which is bounded.) The solutions are $y=\cos(x)$ and $y=\sin(x)$, and $y'$ is not in $L^2$ in either case. Did I misunderstand what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, my guess is that if I am given a solution, $y(x) \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ then its derivative is also from $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. You gave an example for which the solution $y(x)$ is not in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and neither is its derivative. But, that is not what I am looking for. That is, the solution $y(x)$ needs to be in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ so that it meets the requirements I assumed. Maybe, I wasn't clear in the question, I'll try expressing it a bit clearer.

Comment: Can you give an example that is not empty except for the zero solution? $y(x)=e^{-x^2/2}$ does not seem to work, as $f(x)=x^2-1$ is not bounded. Try $y(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}$ to get $y'=-\frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2}$, $y''=\frac{8x^2-2}{(1+x^2)^2}y$ should work. This seems to hint, from the 3 examples seen so far, that $f$ needs to be slowly falling, not only bounded, giving slowly falling solutions.